# one liner to extract ip address with last octet replaced with 0

Tags: bash, awk, beagleboneblack, busybox

I have  Beaglebone Black based custom board,
I want to extract ip address of an interface eth0 and replace fourth octet with 0.
I am using below one liner for extracting ip,

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk  '$1=="inet"{print $2}'
output : 192.168.2.158/24

Expected output : 192.168.2.0/24
```

however I am not able to make fourth octet 0, I thought of using function `gsub` however not able to get right combination. :(

I don't want more pipes in the command.

Any suggestion/pointers ?

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Aren't you replacing the fourth there?

Comment: Does it have GNU awk?

Comment: @123 oops.. you right I want to replace 4th.

Comment: Nope it has busybox awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on expected output: replacing the fourth octet.

```
ip addr show eth0  |awk '/inet / {split($2,a,".");split($2,b,"/");print a[1] "." a[2] "." a[3] ".0/" b[2]}'
142.133.152.0/25
```

If its the 3rd octet:

```
ip addr show eth0  |awk '/inet / {split($2,a,".");print a[1] "." a[2] ".0." a[4] }'
142.133.0.192/25
```

Comment: That will match inet and inet6

Comment: Oh okay, didn't see that

Comment: Because of simplicity I used this one. Others reading my script will quickly understand it. Regex is kind of intimidating for guys looks at script for the first time(its intimidating for me also :) ).

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
$ ip addr show eth0 | sed -nE '/^\s*inet\b/ s/^\s*inet\s*(([0-9]+\.){3})[0-9]+(\S+).*/\10\3/p'
192.168.1.0/24
```

- `/^\s*inet\b/` filter only required line
- `s/^\s*inet\s*(([0-9]+\.){3})[0-9]+(\S+).*/\10\3/` capture sequence of numbers followed by `.` thrice, leave out next number sequence and then capture non-space characters. Replace as per requirement
- Some versions might work with `sed -nr` instead of `sed -nE`

Comment: in busybox shell(ash) above command doesn't work :( Just curious when sed is mix of '/' and '\' isn't that good to use `:` or `|` as separator ? e.g. `sed 's:<search string>:<replace string>:p` or sed 's|<search string>|<replace string>|p`. I generally do that. is there any pit fall there?

Comment: using different separator helps when dealing with `/` which is not the case in my example... `not working` is too broad.. what exactly is going wrong? error msg?

Comment: I get following error `sed: invalid option -- 'E' BusyBox v1.20.2 (2016-09-23 19:08:29 EDT) multi-call binary. Usage: sed [-inr] [-f FILE]... [-e CMD]... [FILE]... or: sed [-inr] CMD [FILE]...`

Comment: can you try `sed -nr` instead of `sed -nE`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok for you ?

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk  '$1=="inet" {gsub(".[0-9]*/24",".0/24",$2);print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last octet of the address and the slash with `0/`:

```
ip addr show eth0 | awk '$1=="inet"{sub(/[0-9]+\//, "0/", $2); print $2}'
```